# Adding items to a HashMap while looping with Iterator

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap, listiterator

I have a program that loops through a HashMap using an Iterator, and inside the loop, I'm adding to the HashMap - which is causing a ConcurrentModificationException. I've seen that ListIterator has an add() function that handles this, but Iterator does not.

The HashMap is set up like this -

```
HashMap<Pair<Integer, Integer>, Object>
```

And the iterator like this -

```
Iterator<Entry<Pair<Integer, Integer>, Object>> iter;
```

With Object (not the real name) being a class from my program.
Does anybody know how I can go about adding to the iterator while I'm looping or any other options?

Comment: Why don't you add objects to a list and add them to the map after the iteration is over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loop through a copy of the map instead, and add to the original map. The entry set of a map is a view of the Map's key value pairs, and does not support addition though you can remove items.

Alternatively you can add elements to a new map while iterating and then use `putAll()` afterwards ... come to think of it, that is probably more efficient.