# Java iterator-like construct for concurrent map modification

Tags: java, concurrentmodification

Let's say I do something like:

```
for (X x : some_map.values ())
    doSomething (x);
```

where `doSomething()` indirectly through several layers of code adds more values to `some_map`. With iterators (as in the example code above), I get `ConcurrentModificationException` thrown into my face.

I can make `some_map` a `LinkedHashMap`, i.e. have predictable iteration order. Also, when a new item is added to it, it is always added at the end of iteration order. In other words, if `ConcurrentModificationException` somehow *wasn't* thrown, the loop would just iterate through the newly added items at the end, i.e. would work perfectly fine. Or, to put it differently, I *do have* a concurrent modification here, but I can guarantee that its behavior is well-defined and not a mistake.

**Question: is there something "similar" to iterators I could use in the above loop to avoid concurrent modification exceptions?**

Note that because of some additional constraints I cannot make the point where items are added aware of the loop. I also cannot change this to something that's not a map. This is just one piece of code, but `some_map` is also used elsewhere and is a map for a reason.

**EDIT:**
My question is if I can iterate (not necessarily in a standard way) the same map I add items to. It's obvious I can instead iterate a copy, after the loop compare said copy with original to find new items, iterate over those and so on. The question is, **can I avoid this completely**, because in my case the only problem is over-eager throwing of `ConcurrentModificationException`. An answer "no, you cannot" is better for me than "you can do ... instead", because I can devise an alternate code for this myself. I just wonder if I overlooked some elegant solution.

Comment: You could keep track of which elements that should be added, then rerun the function on these until there are no more elements to add. After you're done with all iterations, you could add all the new elements in order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding items to a HashMap while looping with Iterator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798671/adding-items-to-a-hashmap-while-looping-with-iterator)

Comment: If a new value has been concurrently added you want to be able to see it directly if you iterate over the values at the same time?

Comment: @marstran: This is not an option, because the place where items are added doesn't know anything about the loop and cannot have any workarounds (like adding to some other collection) because of that.

Comment: Just clarifying: if `doSomething()` adds an entry to the map, you want your loop to also iterate for that value? Ie you want your iteration to "see" changes to your map. If so, what about modification to an entry's value and removals?

Comment: @NicolasFilotto: Ideally yes, though the loop could be modified. However, what I cannot modify is the point where new items are added.

Comment: @Bohemian: Yes, the loop should see new values. Items are never going to be removed or modified. I.e. in this case I just know that all possible concurrent modifications are OK. But implementation (`LinkedHashMap`) doesn't know that and throws `ConcurrentModificationException` because it assumes the modification was not correct.

Comment: @doublep Then I would probably consider some refactorings to break some of the dependencies you have in your code. This shouldn't really be a problem if it's done the right way in the first place.

Comment: @doublep I really think it's a code smell when you __have to__ add elements to a collection while you are iterating over it. But of course, sometimes it's out of your control, and you have to work around it :)

Answer (score 0):

One trick I use to process a list while iterating it, when such processing involves removing elements, is to access it with an decreasing index and removing items at the end.

```
for(int i=myList.size()-1;i>=0;i--) {
        Object item = myList.get(i);
        if(needsToBeRemoved(item)) {
            myList.remove(i);
        }
}
```

This way you can manipulate the list while iterating it. This is valid for lists since you can access its elements by index besides iterator.

You could also apply same technique when processing maps if it follows some kind of sorting that is not altered when processing (ordered map).

If you want or need to use iterators then there is no other option than duplicating information (using a second map)

**Update**:

You can also use a helper iterator (a list of the keys). E.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(1L, "Start");
        map.put(10L, "End");

        // This throws ConcurrentModificationException
        // for (Long value : map.keySet()) {
        // map.put(value + 1, "Other");
        // }
        for (Long value : new ArrayList<Long>(map.keySet())) {
            // This works ok
            map.put(value + 1, "Other");
        }

        System.out.println(map);
        // Prints: {1=Start, 2=Other, 10=End, 11=Other}
    }
```

Comment: I have a map, not a list. I cannot convert it from a map because it needs to be a map for other purposes.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit controversal, but if you don't care about concurrent modification, why don't you use `LinkedHashMap` and ignore `ConcurrentModificationException`?

Basically:

```
try {
   myMap.values().forEach(this::doSomething);
}
catch (ConcurrentModificationException ignored) {
}
```

I think this will work with `LinkedHashMap` but it's clearly not the intended use. You can, however, implement your own version which would be intended for such use.

The "right" way would be to make a copies of values or keys you want to iterate over and then check if something was added. Roughly:

```
final Set<K> processedKeys = new HashSet<>();

do {
   final Set<K> keysToProcess = new HashSet<>(myMap.keySet());
   keysToProcess.removeAll(processedKeys);
   keysToProcess.forEach(key -> doSomething(myMap.get(key)));
} while (!keysToProcess.isEmpty());
```

**Update** for @doublep and @RealSkeptic - why I think just ignoring exception in `myMap.values().forEach(this::doSomething);` will work.

Please see the code for `forEach` or the collection returned by `values()` in `LinkedHashMap`:

```
    public final void forEach(Consumer<? super V> action) {
        if (action == null)
            throw new NullPointerException();
        int mc = modCount;
        for (LinkedHashMap.Entry<K,V> e = head; e != null; e = e.after)
            action.accept(e.value);
        if (modCount != mc)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
```

So `forEach` iterates over the linked list. If values are added to the map they will be added to the list so the `for` loop will iterate till it reaches the end of the linked list. And first *then* the method checks for the modification count. So the action will be effectively applied to all values, even newly added ones.

Comment: How is ignoring the exception going to help? You'll just stay stuck at the same place in the iterator, won't you?

Comment: In the first example I'm pretty sure values after `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown will never be processed by the loop, which is completely incorrect. About the second, thank you, but that's not what the question about. Yes, I know I could rewrite it this way, but please read the edit.

Comment: @RealSkeptic See my update. No, you won't. `forEach` only checks for modification at the end of iteration. This is, however, implementation specific.

Comment: @lexicore: You are right, with `forEach()` it's different. But I don't want to depend on something (i.e. whether it throws only at the end or checks after every iteration) that can be seen as an implementation detail. I think I'll upvote this as a valid answer, but I won't accept it ;)

Comment: @doublep Well, you've asked for "not necessarily in a standard way", so here you go. :)

Comment: @doublep And don't forget, the fact that you get `ConcurrentModificationException` *is also* an implementation detail. The problem here isn't that it is an implementation detail but that it is an undocumented implementation detail/not part of the contract.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over the indices rather than the actual collection is little known trick that would do the job here. You can get the n-th element using the stream API. I'm not sure how efficient that would be, because of all the intermediate objects created.

```
LinkedHashMap<String, String> lhm = new LinkedHashMap();        
// fill lhm
for ( int idx=0; idx < lhm.size(); idx++ ) {
    String val = lhm.values().stream().skip(idx).findFirst().get();
    // process val...
}
```

Comment: It transforms `O(n)` simple iteration into `O(n²)`. Not great, even if in my case in practice `n` is usually not large.

Comment: Not necessarily - but the implementation of values(), stream() and skip() need to be optimized and use the list LinkedHashMap maintains. I'm not sure that's the case, though.

Comment: The list is linked, not random access. Therefore, `skip()` just cannot be `O(1)`, it's `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no built-in way, but it's not that hard if you use a variant of the producer/consumer pattern where the processing queue is refreshed every iteration:

```
Map<K, V> map; // assuming
Set<V> processed = new HashSet<>();
while (!map.values().containsAll(processed)) {
    List<V> queue = new ArrayList<>(map.values());
    queue.removeAll(processed);
    V x = queue.get(0);
    processed.add(x);
    doSomething(x);
}
```